# How to use declared variable for if statement in variables declarations in azure pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

this is my variable declaration section in `azure-pipelines.yml`, but at the moment even if the `branchName` is either **prod** or **dev**, the `buildScript` variable will be set from the `else` clause

What am I missing for the if/else clause to use the correct value?

```
variables:
  npm_config_cache: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/.npm'
  ${{ if startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/') }}:
    branchName: $[ replace(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/', '') ]
  ${{ if startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/pull/') }}:
    branchName: $[ replace(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'], 'refs/heads/', '') ]
  ${{ if or(eq(variables['branchName'], 'prod'), eq(variables['branchName'], 'dev')) }}:
    buildScript: 'npm run build:$(branchName)'
  ${{ else }}:
    buildScript: 'npm run build'
```

Comment: You could add a step to print the branchName to check if it is correct

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `System.PullRequest.TargetBranch` in [template expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) (I mean `${{}}`)

[image]

So instead of this, you could use the bash/pwsh step to evaluate the branch name properly.

```
$sourceBranch = "$(Build.SourceBranch)"

if ( $sourceBranch -match "refs/heads/")
{
  $branchName = $sourceBranch.replace('refs/heads/','')
}
elseif ( $sourceBranch -match "refs/pull/")
{
  $targetBranch = "$(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch)"
  $branchName = $targetBranch.replace('refs/heads/','')
}

if ($branchName -eq "prod" -or $branchName -eq "dev")
{
  $buildScript = "npm run build:$branchName"
  Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildScript;]$buildScript"
}
else {
  $buildScript = "npm run build"
  Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildScript;]$buildScript"
}
```

This is not possible to do with filtering at the variable level.